# Can't use self.size for UIView subclass written in Objective-C but imported to swift project?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

Right now I have a StarView which is a subclass of a UIView. It works fine in another project, but when I imported it into a new swift project, I'm getting the error..."Property 'size' not found on objet of type 'StarView'.

```
- (instancetype)initWithGalaxySize:(CGSize)galaxySize
                     colorMode:(GalaxyColorMode)colorMode
              andShouldFlicker:(BOOL)shouldFlicker
{
self = [super initWithGalaxySize:galaxySize
                       colorMode:colorMode
                andShouldFlicker:shouldFlicker];
if (self)
{
    // Size
    self.size = CGSizeMake(10.0f, 10.0f);

    // Scale
    CGFloat randomScale = floatInRange(0.4f, 0.8f);
    self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(randomScale, randomScale);

    // Rotation
    self.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(self.transform, degreesToRadians(floatInRange(0.0f, 360.0f)));
}

return self;
}
```

Any idea why it won't let me call self.size? I also get the same errors for self.width and self.height.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UIView uses `self.frame.size` or `self.bounds.size` depending on which coordinate space you want.